# Unable to access routes without index.php in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

Ok, so I have spent a considerable amount of time googling for suggestions for this, and despite setting up several test project in Laravel 4 before on WAMPserver, I am not sure what I am missing in this case. Hopefully I have provided all details necessary on my setup and what I have tried so far.

WAMPserver version 2.4, located in C:/wamp/
Apache version 2.4.4
PHP version 5.4.12
mod_rewrite enabled (I can see it in phpinfo())
Project located in C:/wamp/www/wsrp/

in **C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public** I have the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  # Handle Front Controller...
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my **C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/httpd.conf** file I have uncommented this line:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In my **C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.4.4/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf** file I have the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public"
    ServerName localhost
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my **C:/wamp/www/wsrp/app/routes.php** file I have this test route:

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    echo 'Hello world!';
});
```

To test I am trying to visit this URL:

`http://localhost/wsrp/test`

And this doesn't work, it shows me an Internal Server Error page. If however I visit this URL:

`http://localhost/wsrp/index.php/test`

I see my 'Hello world!' message displayed.

Obviously I want to be able to work on this project without having the index.php in the URL, that is the problem.

Of all the SO questions/answers I have looked at, they have all suggested adding a virtual host, which I've done, having the right .htaccess file in **C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public/** which I've done, having `mod_rewrite` enabled, which I've done and yeah.. not sure what else to try, or what I am missing. Help and suggestions greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that I also have an alias file in **C:/wamp/alias/wsrp.conf**

```
Alias /wsrp "c:/wamp/www/wsrp/public"

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/wsrp/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Add a `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` directive to your vhosts file

Comment: Tried adding that to the vhost file, as below:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public"
    ServerName localhost
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/wsrp/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
and restarted WAMPserver, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Don't add it in the `Directory` block; just in the `VirtualHost` block

Comment: Woops, moved it to just in the `VirtualHost` block, restarted server, but still, no dice. Just to check, it doesn't need to be in the main localhost vhost in the block above this one? Also, does it matter on the order of the `DirectoryIndex` in relation to the rest of the block?

Comment: The `Directory` block is totally irrelevant as the root `www` directory setup by apache has all the info it would need including `AllowOverride all` as default in httpd.conf.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to try next then please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly why do you have a localhost v-host? The root directory for WAMP servers is typically `c:/wamp/www` that is already mapped by `HOSTS` to 127.0.0.1 or localhost. That v-host is irrelevant.

Secondly, as your `c:/wamp/www` directory is being used to contain your sites, httpd.conf already contains the `<Directory>` details it needs, from memory it looks something like:

```
<Directory c:/wamp/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

You don't need to define any special directory information for sub directories unless you want to add specific module configuration or change any of the defaults. To get your vhost working you need add no more than:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mylocalsite.dev
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/mysite/public
</VirtualHost>
```

I would suggest however that you put in locations for error logging / access logging.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add in OP that I have an alias file too (added to OP), I guess that will have a bearing on it too? I just can't for the life of me work out what is going wrong, I have had working installations of Laravel on WampServer before, with no `index.php` and no `public` in the URL..

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem that you. I solved this problem in this way.

1. Open **C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf/httpd.conf**
2. Then, You may search the next line, **#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**
3. **Remove the pound ('#')** sign at the start and **save the file.**
4. Next, **restart** your WampServer and test.

I hope help you!

Comment: As stated in the OP, I do already have mod_rewrite enabled unfortunately, so that won't help me.

Comment: @JamesVassie you should need to mention it before, you don't need to drop his point, I have tested it and it worked for me, I give him up. thanks Gustoko

Comment: @UsmanAli don't know quite what you mean. As in my previous comment, and in the OP - I had already mentioned that I had mod_rewrite enabled, so his answer wasn't going to be of any help unfortunately.

Comment: Even though it might not be the correct answer for the OP, fwiw I stumbled across this post and this answer provided the solution for me.